# Does making a planet a Homeworld remove mobs from a dungeon?

Tags: starbound

I read that when you make a world your Homeworld you practically control every aspect of it.

I am wondering, if a world had a dungeon like a Glitch Castle which has hostile enemies in it, would dungeons like this become empty of hostiles?

Comment: AFAIK, making a world your home doesn't do anything except make a bookmark of it so you can easily return to it. This will likely change as the game gets more features.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, making a planet your home planet does nothing other then giving it a bookmarked location so that you can easily find your way back to it.

In the patch notes for the game, the devs have specifically talked about adding in new features further in that will allow someone to change the climate, geography, and spawn rate on their planet when they've marked it as home.  Currently, though, there's nothing.  So we'll have to wait.